# Excel - Split data into tables according to two criteria

Tags: excel

I have a raw data wherein I wanted to split it according to the criteria of reasons assigned but then it will be also by date.

So when i have my sample raw data here :

```
Col1                 Col2                  Col3              Col4
Row1-Sample          Figure1               To be rcvd          02/11/1996
Row2-Sample          Figure1               To be rcvd          02/11/1996
Row3-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd          04/11/1996
Row4-Sample          Figure1               To be rcvd          02/11/1996
Row5-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd          05/11/1996
```

I would get :

```
      Col1                 Col2                  Col3              Col4

    Row2-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd         02/11/1996
    Row3-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd         02/11/1996
```

SheetName = Feb_Col4

The sheet name must be the date + the reason(Col3)

```
  Col1                 Col2                  Col3              Col4
Row2-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd         02/11/1996
Row3-Sample          Figure1               To be dlvd         04/11/1996
```

Is there anyone who can give me idea how to start this.

Comment: Row2 is in both example, why? please specify what type of idea do you need? Do you know VBA and need help what should be the flow of your code, or do you need help to learn VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can go two directions from here:

1. It is my advice with all data manipulation to store all data in one     MS-Access file, manipulate the data using SQL (not difficult to
   master), and report the results in MS-Excel using an ODBC
   connection.
2. If you want to continue with MS-Excel you can make a pivot table from this dataset (Insert -> Pivot Table). Before you make the pivot table prepare the data by concatenating Col3 and col4 in Col5 (called Tab in this example) 
   `(=C2&" "&text(D2,"YYYY-MM-DD")` and make an extra column with the value 1 (count the row). Then define the pivot table with cols 1,2,3 and 4 in the row header and the count value in the value field (display the pivot table with classic layout). Swith the subtotals off in all fields in the row header. Put the new column 'Tab' in the 'report filter' field of the pivot table.

[image: Pivot now loks like this with one selection in Col5]

(*Aplogizing for the Dutch language in the excel result, but I'm convinced it helps to explain.*)

Now you can create one tab per value of the 'Tab' column by using the pivot table command 'show report filter pages'.

[image]